# Is it possible to set fig.scap for table (instead for figure) genrated by a code chunk?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, caption, xtable

I have a table generated by knitr code chunk. The table is printed using `xtable`. Its caption is set inside the `xtable` function. This label is too long to be displayed in the list of tables in the beginning of the document. Therefore I want to set a short label which will be used instead the long label in this list.

For plots generated this label can be set by the chunk option `fig.scap`, but when I tried to use it for a table, the long label remains in list of tables.

I think I would be able to deal with this using `\captionof{table}[short label]{long label}` outside the code chunk, but it is not a very straightforward way and I'm afraid I would get problems to stuck table and its caption together. Is there some better way to do it?

The code (with artificial data):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, english]{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Intoduction}
<<Chunk1, results="asis", echo=FALSE, fig.scap= "short caption - tab">>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(head(iris), caption="long caption of the table"))
@

<<Chunk2, results="asis", echo=FALSE,fig.align="center", fig.cap = "Long caption of the figure", fig.scap= "short caption - fig">>=
plot(iris[,1:2])
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a "short caption" to be used in the List of Figures, pass a character vector of length 2 to the `caption` argument of `xtable`. From `?xtable`:

> `caption`: Character vector of length 1 or 2 containing the table's caption or title. If length is 2, the second item is the "short caption" used when LaTeX generates a "List of Tables"

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
<<echo = FALSE, results = "asis">>=
xtable::xtable(head(iris), caption = c("Long Caption", "Short"))
@
\end{document}
```